# How does FindContours function from OpenCV library work?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I can't find any information about what methods are implemented in FindContours function. I need related papers or just names of involved algorithms.

Answer (score 11):

Look in the [OpenCV API](https://picoforge.int-evry.fr/projects/svn/gpucv/opencv_doc/2.1/opencv.pdf).  This is what it says on page 344, where `FindContours` is described:

> The function retrieves contours from
>   the binary image using the algorithm
>   [19]. The contours are a useful tool
>   for shape analysis and object
>   detection and recognition.

If you look in the bibliography at the end of the document, this is reference 19:

> S. Suzuki and K. Abe. Topological
>   structural analysis of digitized
>   binary images by border following.
>   CVGIP, 30(1):32–46, April 1985.

Sounds like a good starting point.  Also, there's always the source if you want explicit implementation details.